# Correctly wrap double quote to SSRS report parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am not working on a SQL report and one value needs double quotes added on both side. The definition of this value is like the following:

```
<Value>=Parameters!ParamSearchTerm.Value</Value>
```

I've tried with some solutions such as adding `"""` on both sides or add `char(34)` on both sides, however they don't work.

This is how I've done with Char(34):

```
<Value>=Parameters!Char(34)+ParamSearchTerm.Value+Char(34)</Value>
```

The result shows an error: The value express for the query parameter @ParamSearchTerm refers to a non-existing report parameter 'Char'.

I've also tried with lower case char, still not working.

[image]

Comment: 1. How you are using Char(34). Can you show the exact string as that will make it easier to troubleshoot. 2. Are you getting any error or is it just showing the wrong result?

Comment: Instead of ampersand (&) try plus (+) sign.
`<Value>=Chr(34) + "Parameters!ParamSearchTerm.Value" + Chr(34)</Value>`

Comment: Thank you. No error message anymore but still not solved my issue, originally if I put search keywords in double quotes manually, it produces correct output. However when I tried this solution, it won't return any search result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**1ST SOLUTION:**

```
<Value>= "'" +"'" + Parameters!ParamSearchTerm.Value + "'" + "'"</Value>
```

This will shows like a double quote but I know this is not the best way just an alternative way.

**2ND SOLUTION:**

```
=Chr(34) & "Parameters!ParamSearchTerm.Value" & Chr(34)
```

or

```
=Chr(34) + "Parameters!ParamSearchTerm.Value" + Chr(34)
```

**3RD SOLUTION**

```
="""Parameters!ParamSearchTerm.Value"""
```

Hopes I help.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but this does not solve my issue, I was trying to wrap the search term parameter in order to do the full-text search.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to put double quote on the Paramater. My solutions works only on the expressions of textboxes.

Comment: You should do your double quote work in the sql. Not in the parameter.

Comment: This is because I was trying to guide users to do full text search if they give input parameters, the report cannot accept some parameters which are the keywords reserved by SQL server. That's why I try to wrap them into double quote.